# How to Create default .keystore file OR restore .keystore

Tags: java, keystore, jarsigner, jar-signing

When I try to run

```
calabash-android resign ContactManager.apk
```

I get Following Error.

```
2013-04-03 21:29:38 - "C:\Java\jdk1.7.0_17/bin/jarsigner.exe" -sigalg MD5withRSA
 -digestalg SHA1 -signedjar C:/Users/Win7/Desktop/ContactManager/bin/ContactMana
ger.apk -storepass  -keystore "C:/Users/Win7/Desktop/ContactManager/bin" C:/User
s/Win7/AppData/Local/Temp/d20130403-3608-3wwsb/unsigned.apk
**jarsigner error: java.lang.RuntimeException: keystore load: C:\Users\Win7\.keyst
ore (The system cannot find the file specified)**
jarsigner command: "C:\Java\jdk1.7.0_17/bin/jarsigner.exe" -sigalg MD5withRSA -d
igestalg SHA1 -signedjar C:/Users/Win7/Desktop/ContactManager/bin/ContactManager
.apk -storepass  -keystore "C:/Users/Win7/Desktop/ContactManager/bin" C:/Users/W
in7/AppData/Local/Temp/d20130403-3608-3wwsb/unsigned.apk
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/calabash-android-0.4.3.pre5/lib/calabash-andro
id/helpers.rb:79:in `sign_apk': Could not sign app (C:/Users/Win7/AppData/Local/
Temp/d20130403-3608-3wwsb/unsigned.apk (RuntimeError)
        from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/calabash-android-0.4.3.pre5/lib/c
alabash-android/helpers.rb:62:in `resign_apk'
        from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/tmpdir.rb:129:in `mktmpdir'
        from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/calabash-android-0.4.3.pre5/lib/c
alabash-android/helpers.rb:55:in `resign_apk'
        from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/calabash-android-0.4.3.pre5/bin/c
alabash-android:112
        from C:/Ruby187/bin/calabash-android:19:in `load'
        from C:/Ruby187/bin/calabash-android:19
```

I suspect this might be causing Issue.

```
jarsigner error: java.lang.RuntimeException: keystore load: C:\Users\Win7\.keyst
    ore (The system cannot find the file specified)
```

How Do I generate the .keystore File. I am not that much into JAVA, so may be this is a simple question.